# ¿Cómo puedo leer un elemento de Movie y ponerlo en una celda de Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

No puedo leer el objeto Movie, alguien puede guiarme, es un script en VBA, lo que intento es leer un JSON de una API publica, para ubicar los datos en excel, todo funciona e incluso en el depurador puedo ver los datos que tiene Movie, pero a la hora de intentar leer sus elementos me marca un error el depurador, alguien sabe ¿por que?

```
Sub getData()

    Dim Movie As Object
    Dim R As Object
    Dim scriptControl As Object

    Set scriptControl = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
    scriptControl.Language = "JScript"

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/shift/", False
        .send
        Set R = scriptControl.Eval("(" + .responsetext + ")")
        .abort
        With Sheets("API")
            For Each Movie In R
                MsgBox (Movie.Name)
                .Cells(1, 2).Value = Movie.price_btc
                .Cells(1, 3).Value = Movie.price_usd
                .Cells(1, 4).Value = Movie.Rank
            Next Movie
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

En la siguiente imagen puede verse el depurador y su contenido, el problema es que cuando leo este contenido por alguna razón truena.

[image: Imagen de depurador]

La idea seria como puedo leer un elemento de Movie y ponerlo en una celda de Excel?

Comment: Hola @user3215778. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Por qué? ¿Cuál es el error? ¿Qué hiciste para depurarlo? ¿Cómo podríamos entender qué está pasando sin tener que intentar ejecutar todo tu código, algo que no es inmediato? ¿Desde dónde se ejecuta? ¿Cuál es la función que debería realizar? Por favor lee [mcve]

Comment: @user3215778, ¿tal vez sea porque la propiedad `Name` es en realidad `name`?, prueba cambiando `Movie.Name` a `Movie.name`.

Comment: La solución debería publicarse como respuesta no como parte del contenido de la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

> Contenido tomado de la pregunta el cual fue publicado por el OP en la [version 4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/37728/4)

Ya me resolvieron:

```
Sub getData()

    Dim Movie As Object
    Dim R As Object
    Dim sc As Object, x

    Set sc = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
    sc.Language = "JScript"

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/shift/", False
        .send
        sc.Eval ("var i, o = (" + .responsetext + ")")
        sc.Eval "function l(){return o.length;}"
        sc.Eval "function indx(n){i=n;}"
        sc.Eval "function p(pname){return o[i][pname];}"

        .abort

        With Sheets(1)
            For x = 1 To sc.Eval("l()")
                sc.Eval "indx(" & x - 1 & ")" 'set array index

                'get properties at that index
                .Cells(1, 2).Value = sc.Eval("p('name')")
                .Cells(1, 2).Value = sc.Eval("p('price_btc')")
                .Cells(1, 3).Value = sc.Eval("p('price_usd')")
                .Cells(1, 4).Value = sc.Eval("p('Rank')")

            Next x
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```